# Guess my number in limited tries game

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, while-loop

As part of my course at university I am learning python a task I have been trying to (re)write this guess the number game to terminate if the user fails to guess correctly within 5 tries:

```
    # Guess My Number Mod 5 tries or bust


import random  

print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in five tries or less")

my_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Go on, Take a guess, I dare ya "))
tries = 1

while guess != my_number:
    if guess > my_number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")
guess = int(input("Go on, Take a guess, I dare ya "))
tries += 1
if tries==5:
        input("You failed to guess the number was it that hard?\n Press any key to exit!)"

print("Well done you guessed correctly!The number was", my_number)
print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

I assume the termination cause isn't working as my if statement is outside the while loop and I can't get it to take effect.

Also some invalid syntax as I'm tired and can't spot it.

If possible can you guys give me hints on how to fix what I want to do as I am more likely to learn that way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistake, I've changed it above. Also ideally I should have placed commas but don't be a grammar Nazi. There are more important things in the world

Answer (score 3):

You are looking to **[break](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)** out a loop when hitting a certain condition.

```
if condition:
            # do something
            break # brings you out of the loop
```

Comment: My tutor would kill me if I ever used break lol I looked around anyway and fixed it didn't realize I could use an and operator whilst composing the loop e.g: while guess != my_number and tries<=4: that work thanks for rapid response anyway mate

Comment: `break` isn't a **bad** thing.

Comment: Yeah it seems handy to me but according to my tutor it is a way out for lazy programming and there always simply a better loop that could be used w/o break but ah well :)

Comment: There are times, where you want to break out of the loop after you have done a few instructions in a loop. Without break, it would be impossible to do

Comment: @MANICX100: I have to agree with Cthuhu and Bartlomiej. break isn't a bad thing. In fact it is totally necessary. Whereas using goto statement is considered bad practice generally. Hope you didn't get them mixed up in some way.